# supporting multiple Android device screen resolutions, using native 1080 x 1920 to scale down

Tags: android, scale, screen-resolution

This is a problem of supporting multiple Android device screen resolutions.  The App is fixed in portrait orientation and there are three parts of the App,

1. A top bar (fixed height, say 100px at full HD 1080 resolution)
2. Main body (dynamic height)

   - My approach is to build the App with 1080 x 1920 natively, and let the app scale down for the target device screen.
     ** Since the main body is having dynamic height, the scale would be simply (target width/1080)
     *** I have also worked out the height for the main body in different resolutions, whether there is a soft home button bar or not, I can work out the exact height to use in px.

I have tried two ways doing the scale, but both of them got some problems.

=== Method 1 ===
 - Scale the top bar and put at the top (no prlblem, 50 px in this case)
 - Let the main body to auto fill with "0dip" + "weight = 1" (problem described below)

Problem: If doesn't matter the order of applying the parameters, the scale is always applied after the 0dip and weight is set and to fit the screen size, so in a non-1080x1920

situation, the main body would actually be scaled down further.  e.g. say if the device is 540 x 960, and the main body part is supposedly occupying a 490 x 960 area.  Having the

"0dip" + "weight = 1" with a scale factor of 0.5 in this case supposedly to scale from the 1080 size, the actual main body would actually shown as a 245 x 480 area in the main of

the 490x960 space allocated for it.  In a full HD case, whether it is 1080 x 1920 (without the soft home bar) or 1080 x 18xx (with the soft home bar), since the scale factor is "1"

(no scale), the auto fill is working perfectly across different screen height.  When it is not 1080, the scale is applied at the

(You may like to say, then, just don't scale the main body part, then the screen occupying is perfect, however, then items are shown at the 1080 size, so you only see part of the

content, 25% top left part in this case)

This then lead me to my 2nd method
=== Method 2===
 - Scale the top bar and put at the top (no prlblem)
 - Set the main body area to be 1080 x 1920 at layout, then at run time, work out the actual target width and height, set the area to the size for scaling, scale it accordingly then

calculate a margin to bring the part in correct position

Say if the target screen is 800 x 1205 (1280 - 75 the soft home button bar)
The scale = 0.74074074  (800/1080)
Top Bar will take 74 px in this case
Main body would supposedly have 1131 px

After scale before the margin was applied, the main body is only partially shown with a black padding on the left and top, I was assuming it was center placed in a 1080 x 1920

space, so to work out the margin to bring it in cirrect position, i got the fomula below

Left moving px = (1080 - TargetWidth) / 2   => always working correctly with different screen res
Up moving ps = (((1920 - TargetHeight) / 2) - TopBar Height )   => not working, got a weird padding from screen to screen  Note that the TargetHeight is the full height including the TopBar to be occupied

I did a screen pixel analysis first, I found that in this 800 x 1205 case, the black space at the top between the top bar and the main body was 306
That obviously has something to do with the top bar 74 pixels, together the top space was 380
However, consider the full target height was 1205, with 2 x 380, that is 1965 pixels, and i can make the formula work for this screen if I add 45 pixel to the calculation.

BUT, when the resolution changes, the gap is different, that amount of extra pixel is just random....

=========================

My questions

1. Are there better ways to achieve what I am intended to achieve?
2. Is there a way to use "0dip" + "weight = 1" + apply a scale which doesn't cause 2x shrink?
3. What is the mystery margin amount there, or maybe i have missed something and could have get it right with some correction?

Thanks, any help would be very much appreciated.